# How to highlight a selected cell

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list item so I want to highlight the item that is selected. How do I achieve that?

Below is the code

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-expanded="false">
      Dashboard
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a *ngIf="enableActivityDashboardFeature" class="dropdown-item selected" href="#"
        [routerLink]="['dashboarda']">Dashboarda</a>
      <a *ngIf="enableActualsDashboardFeature" class="dropdown-item" href="#"
        [routerLink]="['dashboard']">DashboardA</a>
      <a *ngIf="enableActualsDashboardBetaFeature" class="dropdown-item" href="#"
        [routerLink]="['dashboardb']">DashboardB</a>
      <a *ngIf="enableGrillsDashboardFeature" class="dropdown-item" href="#"
        [routerLink]="['dashboardc']">Dashboardcs</a>
      <a *ngIf="enableGrillsV2DashboardFeature" class="dropdown-item" href="#"
        [routerLink]="['dashboardd']">Dashboardd</a>
      <a *ngIf="enableValuationsDashboard" class="dropdown-item" href="#" [routerLink]="['dashboarde']">Dashboarde</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

How do I keep the cell highlighted when I select something from this dropdown?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change selection on click?

Comment: @MichałTkaczyk No i want to highlight the item that i have selected

Comment: So you want to add specific `css` code on `.selected` class. I don't really know what do you mean by highlight, there are few ways to do that, you can i.e. set `background-color` property in your class with color according to your liking. You can set `box-shadow` property, too.

Comment: @MichałTkaczyk So i want to make a div active when you selected that from the list. So may be in class if we type active it will be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use functions in your class for e.g. `<a class="getActive('someName')"></a>`

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-expanded="false">
      Dashboard
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a (click)="setActive('dashboarda')" *ngIf="enableActivityDashboardFeature" class="dropdown-item {{getActive('dashboarda')}}" href="#"
        [routerLink]="['dashboarda']">Dashboarda</a>
      <a (click)="setActive('DashboardA')" *ngIf="enableActualsDashboardFeature" class="dropdown-item {{getActive('DashboardA')}}" href="#"
        [routerLink]="['dashboard']">DashboardA</a>
      <a (click)="setActive('dashboardb')" *ngIf="enableActualsDashboardBetaFeature" class="dropdown-item {{getActive('dashboardb')}}" href="#"
        [routerLink]="['dashboardb']">DashboardB</a>
      <a (click)="setActive('dashboardc')" *ngIf="enableGrillsDashboardFeature" class="dropdown-item {{getActive('dashboardc')}}" href="#"
        [routerLink]="['dashboardc']">Dashboardcs</a>
      <a (click)="setActive('dashboardd')" *ngIf="enableGrillsV2DashboardFeature" class="dropdown-item {{getActive('dashboardd')}}" href="#"
        [routerLink]="['dashboardd']">Dashboardd</a>
      <a (click)="setActive('dashboarde')" *ngIf="enableValuationsDashboard" class="dropdown-item {{getActive('dashboarde')}}" href="#" [routerLink]="['dashboarde']">Dashboarde</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

**In your .ts file:**

```
currentChoice = '';


    setActive(choice: string)
      {
        this.currentChoice = choice;
      }
    
      getActive(choice: string): string{
        if (this.currentChoice === choice) {
        return 'active';
        }
        else {
        return 'not';
        }
      }
```

**and your .css file:**

```
.active{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

And if you want to highlight more than one item in a time you can use a list of Choices.

Comment: Did you check how many times your function `getActive` will be executed? It is not a good approach...

Comment: I get it, there is a different approach that is definitely way better for e.g.: <a #d1 (click)="setActive('d1')"></a> and in the .ts file we can get the anchor from the id using ViewChild as ElemRef to set a new background-color or a class.

Comment: I think the best approach would be adding optional class parameter to template, basing on some variable in .ts file. Part with setting active is ok, but this `ViewChild` idea is too much here. I would just add something like `[class.active]="active === 'd1'"` in template and `this.active = parameterFromFunc` inside `setActive` function.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to do this would be to keep the active cell Id (by Id I mean one of these `dashboarda`) in your component, say we store it in a field called `activeCell`

Then in the html you can simply do

```
<a ... 
    class="dropdown-item"
    [class.selected]="activeCell === 'dashboarda'"
    [routerLink]="['dashboarda']">Dashboarda</a>
```

(`...` is just to skip some code here)

Now you can highlight it in css, either give it a different color, background-color, or even opacity
opacity for example

```
.dropdown-item { opacity: .7 }
.dropdown-item.selected { opacity: 1 }
```

Now all items will have 0.7 opacity but the selected one